# Can't run after changing datamodel in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an iOS application that was working fine. I made a change to the CoreData datamodel to add an attribute to an existing table. Now, it won't run. It gets to where I try to query with an NSPredicate and it blows up with no error.

I've deleted the application inside of the simulator. I've deleted the "Derived Data" directory in Xcode Organizer. I've "cleaned" and rebuilt. I'm not sure what else I can do to "reset" the application.

I know making change to the datamodel can have issues that require a relatively hard reset, but I can't figure out how to move on. All I did was add an "Integer 16" column to a working data model, but now my app is dead.

So, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: did you make the change on the class file as well?

Comment: I regenerated the NSManagedObject subclass. It has the new attribute (which is an Integer 16).

Comment: What "it blows up" means? It crashes? Hangs? The query returns an empty collection?

Comment: When I make a fetch request, the application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening because the version of the Managed Object Model used to save your database is different of the newly modified model.

You should create a new version of your Managed Object Model and then configure Core Data to perform a Lightweight Migration from your previous model version to the newest.

Please follow the [steps detailed in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html).